# Counting time in log file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I've log file in form like below:

**log.txt**

```
Unavailable 06.08.2014 23:59:36 - 07.08.2014 00:00:36
Unavailable 15.08.2014 04:53:32 - 15.08.2014 04:53:32
Available   15.08.2014 04:54:32 - 15.08.2014 05:17:32
Unavailable 15.08.2014 05:18:32 - 15.08.2014 05:18:32
Unavailable 15.08.2014 08:22:00 - 15.08.2014 08:22:00
Available   15.08.2014 08:23:00 - 17.08.2014 01:44:27
Unavailable 17.08.2014 01:45:27 - 17.08.2014 01:52:33
Available   17.08.2014 01:53:33 - 02.09.2014 11:07:21
```

I need to count unavailability time in seconds. I'm not any sed/awk guru so my apporach to this problem is very simple:

```
cat log.txt | grep "Unav" | sed -r 's/\<Unavailable\>//g;s/:/ /g;s/\./ /g' | 
awk -F- '{d2=mktime($2);d1=mktime($1);print d2-d1;}' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

I was suprised seeing that when date came across day (trough midnight) calculation goes wrong. Result from calculation of first line shows that difference was **31449660** seconds in EPOCH, so it will be **Thu Dec 31 01:01:00 CET 1970**. But result of calculation should be 60 seconds. Can someone explain me why this result was returned from system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need all that `sed` and `grep` if you are going to use `awk`. Also, the difference should be 60 seconds as it shows from the sample data.

From the `man` page:

> mktime(datespec) Turn datespec into a timestamp in the same form as is
>   returned by systime(). It is similar to the function of the same name
>   in ISO C. The argument, datespec, is a string of the form "YYYY MM DD
>   HH MM SS [DST]".

Try the following command:

```
awk '
$1 == "Unavailable" { 
    split ($2, d1, /[.]/);
    split ($3, t1, /:/);
    split ($5, d2, /[.]/);
    split ($6, t2, /:/);
    end   = mktime (d2[3]" "d2[2]" "d2[1]" "t2[1]" "t2[2]" "t2[3])
    start = mktime (d1[3]" "d1[2]" "d1[1]" "t1[1]" "t1[2]" "t1[3])
    print end - start
}' log.txt
60
0
0
0
426
```

This will print the difference in seconds. If you wish to print the output in another format you can use the [`strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function from GNU `awk` library.

Comment: As I say I'm not awk guru, but I see that You are thanks a lot.

Comment: As I couldn't upvote your comment in "the answer posted from you know where", I do it here :D

Answer (score 1):

On my system, `man awk` says `mktime(datespec)` requires the format `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS`.  But you are passing `06 08 2014 23 59 36`, which has the year and day swapped.  You'll need to rearrange the fields.